# Review of my T-shirt design

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, pi

I'm a graphics guy and a wanna-be mathematician. Is the T-shirt design below okay? Or if there's a bone headed error, I'd appreciate a heads up.

[image: Pi squared over twelve]

`

Comment: Are the sum on the bottom and the numbers on the top meant to be related?

Comment: @Jahambo99 They're the values of $1/n$, the side lengths of the alternating squares.

Comment: @Jahambo99 The sum is the area that is black.

Comment: @Jahambo99  Yes. The first square is 1x1 square. The second square punched out of the middle of the first is a 1/2 x 1/2 square. The 2nd square is a 1/3 x 1/3 square. Punched out of the middle of that square is 1/4^2. Etc. Edit: Milo Brandt said it much more succinctly.

Comment: Somehow the above numbers and the picture fail to illustrate (for me) why the sum is true.

Comment: The $-1$ should definitely be in parentheses. $-1^{n+1}=-1$ for all $n$, while $(-1)^{n+1}$ alternates between $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Technically the sum isn't alternating: Right now, the $1^{n+1}$ isn't doing anything, you need parentheses around the $-1$. Obviously that will look pretty bad, bunches of parentheses. Maybe you could try using LaTeX or something to typeset in a better way, and you won't need any parentheses.

Comment: @Mejia I don't think the picture is supposed to constitute any sort of proof

Comment: Ah, nevermind then.

Comment: @pjs36 I'm embarrassed to admit I'm LaTex challenged but could probably do a depiction using Adobe Illustrator. If anyone could show me what the caption at the bottom should look like, I'll upvote and check mark the answer.

Comment: Well, most of the other parentheses are unnecessary. To start with, there's no need to put the whole term in parentheses. Next, instead of a factor $(1/n^2)$ the $(-1)^{n+1}$ could just be used as numerator. Doing both would give $\pi^2/12 = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}/n^2$ — that has even less parentheses than the expression as it is now.

Comment: Also, slightly off-topic because it's more typography than mathematics: Using a hyphen as minus sign doesn't look nice.

Comment: You may find latex2png.com/ useful for quickly outputting a nicely formatted sum at whatever resolution in png format. I like Omnomnom's suggestion in the answer: \left. \pi^2\big /12\right. = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\big/n^2

Comment: Not a very mathematical comment, but the bit on top feels off: bring the 1 brace down lower or lift the 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, and maybe 1/5 braces a little bit higher. The 1/3 feels cramped needlessly, and 1/4 is still in large enough font that it really shouldn't be overlapping with the bracket already. I get that there's the conceit with the diagonal line of solid-to-dash transition points, but I don't think it adds very much more interest than some slightly concave-down curve would.

Comment: I agree with Andres Mejia; this is not enlightening as a visual proof. There are several visual proofs of infinite sums that are enlightening. For example: [infinite sum of 1/4^n](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/d0/d1/bfd0d15a529c61d85b7991bbdbc36cf1.jpg)

Comment: the centre should be gray/halftone  not black.

Comment: @user52673 I agree. The OP should have a look at ["proofs without words"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/8846)

Comment: Btw. If you use $\LaTeX$ for the main formula you should consider doing the same for the fractions above, or at least pick the same font (it's called "cmr", Computer Modern Roman).

Comment: $\cos(n\pi)$ is an alternative to consider for $(-1)^n$.

Comment: What's this infinite series called anyway? I like it a lot.

Comment: @user504882:  Look up the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), and be prepared to fall down a rabbit hole.

Comment: I think it would be acceptable for $\sum(-1)^{n+1}(\frac 1n)^2$.  But I don't see that the picture displays the result.  The black areas of the squares is the sum but why does the picture show the result is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$?

Comment: To be frank, I am afraid this should not belong to math SE, but I do not intend to close or something, nor have I the power, as I am not a so poker-faced guy ;)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I would try and optimize the sum at the bottom a bit. Definitely we need parentheses around the $-1$, but just throwing them in will cause a bit of a mess:

$$\pi^2/12 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((-1)^{n+1}(1/n^2))$$

Plus, math that's not typeset well already gives me a less-than-stellar vibe; I'm not a huge fan of the font there.

Instead, you could rewrite the sum a bit, if you have the space for it. The version below takes up only slightly more vertical space than the Sigma, if vertical space is a concern. It's a bit less cluttered, and LaTeX's job (technically Mathjax here) is to make sure the typesetting is as good as possible.

$$\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{12} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$

Comment: Note that you can click the "Edit" button at the bottom of the answer here to see how things were typeset, the syntax.

Comment: Thank you pjs36!  I'm going to use the first version since I'm constrained by the screens my shirt printer uses. It can't be more than 16" tall. Therefore I will use the version that takes less vertical space.

Comment: Sure! And just to be clear, I do like things overall -- especially how even the curly braces at the top all line up well; the transition from end-of-brace to dashed-line are all on a line. But fawning doesn't make a very good answer! :P

Comment: You can also get the $\rm\LaTeX$ form (or a MathML version, in case that for your design you use a program that handles that) by right-clicking on the MathJax formula and selecting the appropriate entry of the "Show Math As" submenu.

Comment: @HopDavid You could shrink the box a little. Or maybe move the 1 up top closer.

Comment: You can save a lot of vertical space by using vertical bars and horizontal arrows around your numbers (somewhat like this drawing: http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me2011/handouts/drawing/index_files/fig_31.jpeg) instead of those huge curly braces. It could also be more legible. That should more than make up for the space required to typeset the sum nicely. (Notice how it's actually the summation symbol that takes up the most vertical space, even in the last formula; writing the fractions vertically doesn't make any difference in the height.)

Answer (score 58):

Yet another pleasing way to write the sum:

## $$
\left. \pi^2\big /12\right. = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\big/n^2 
$$

say, if you wanted to take more horizontal space.

Comment: I like that! But I've already had the silk screener burn the stencil.

Comment: @HopDavid So why did you ask for feedback if you already have the stencil made?

Comment: @Mast Ummm…. No. I asked for feedback. pjs36 and others gave it, and I put the -1 in parenthesis. Then I gave the corrected design to my silkscreener and asked him if he could get me at least 1 shirt before Christmas. Then I saw the above answer.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer to centralise elements that sit on ground level, i.e. the "footprint",  and ignore cantilevered superscripts, e.g.
$$\huge\frac {\;\; \pi^{^2}}{12}\qquad,\qquad \frac 1{\; n^{^2}}$$
which seem more pleasing aesthetically than the standard 
$$\huge\frac {\pi^2}{12} \qquad,\qquad \frac 1{n^2}$$

If we do that then we have 
$$\huge\color{darkblue}{\boxed{\frac {\;\;\;\; \pi^{^2}}{12}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{^{n+1}}\frac1{\;\;n^{^2}}}}$$
or, using default font size for superscripts,
$$\huge\color{darkblue}{\boxed{\frac {\;\;\;\; \pi^2}{12}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac1{\;\;n^2}}}$$

I prefer to separate the $(-1)^{n+1}$ so that it doesn't make the fraction top heavy.

I also prefer that fractions be shown as $\frac ab$ rather than $a/b$ as they are being used in display mode rather than an in-line mathematical expression or a subscript/superscript.

And, of course, for typesetting mathematics, a font with serifs always looks better. Use the image from mathjax here, from the equation writer in Microsoft Word, or from other mathematical typesetting software like $\TeX$.

---

**Note**

It might be interesting to consider the comparison in the picture below, taken from chalkdustmagazine.com [here](http://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/).

$\hspace{4cm}$ [image]

According to the website, the six examples are:

1. Official Chalkdust font editor’s handwriting, using black Parker fountain pen
2. Professional typesetting, from a 1954 UCL maths exam paper,
3. Typewriter, from a 1985 exam paper, in a monospaced font,
4. Microsoft’s pre-2007 equation editor, using Times New Roman,
5. Microsoft’s post-2007 equation editor, using Cambria Math,
6. LaTeX, using Computer Modern.

Notice that in example 1 (handwritten), the $1$ and $n$ are centred, and the superscript $2$ is much smaller than $n$. Hence when writing, it seems to be natural to do this.

For example 2 (manual typesetting), ite seems that the typesetter is trying to centre the $1$ and $n$ as much as possible, although the $2$ is almost the same size as $n$.

For examples 4,5,6 (all computer typesetting systems), the $n$ is off-centre. However, for example 4, the spacing and font size of superscript $2$ seems to be much more pleasing in that it is placed higher than $n$ and is also smaller in size.

Comment: Your superscript 2 in $\pi^2$ is bigger than the superscript 2 in $n^2$, which looks odd to me.

Comment: Yes you noticed that. Somehow I find that the standard font size for $2$ in $\frac 1{n^2}$ is too large and almost the same size as $n$.  However, when the same is applied to $\frac {\pi^2}{\cdot}$ it looks ok.

Comment: For each fraction individually I agree with you, but I think being inconsistent looks worse than using the standard $n^2$. You could use small superscripts for all of them I suppose.

Comment: @Nathaniel - Good. Let's see how that looks.

Comment: It's so hard not to keep nit-picking... now it looks strange because (i) there is a vertical gap between the top of the $pi$ and the baseline of the $2$, which isn't there in the $n^2$ expression, and (ii) because the superscript in $(-1)^{n+1}$ is still in the original size, as are the expressions above and below the summation sign. For point (i) I'm not really sure why that's happening, since the height of the $\pi$ character looks essentially the same as that of the $n$. I think now I'd hedge towards using the original superscript size throughout, while keeping the centred fractions.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I've now kept the font size the same for all superscripts but shown two versions: the first with smaller font size and the second with default font size. Let's see which one readers here prefer.