# Derivative of $\pi^5$

Tags: derivatives, transcendental-numbers

I was scanning google images of math tee shirts when I found this one. [image]
And, including the photo, I have found three different answers. I should say just specifically regarding the derivative of $\pi^5$. Desmos app looks like it has it at $0$. And Wolfram mentions the transcendental aspect of the number. In this case I guess my question is in conceptualising that $\pi$ is a constant and therefore the derivative of a constant is $0$.

Comment: Of course the derivative of $\pi^5$ is zero

Comment: the derivative of $\pi^5$ is equal to Zero, since this is a constant

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really stupid question

Comment: there is no stupid question. he simply didn't get the joke @D_S

Comment: I don't get how it's a joke but okay

Comment: the shirt is a joke... @D_S

Comment: On an unrelated note, I really have no idea who would buy this.  A TA who likes making fun of his students, maybe?  Most people wouldn't even get the joke and of those of us who do, it seems (at least to me) quite insulting.  For comparison, [here](http://www.swarthmore.edu/sites/default/files/assets/images/physics-astronomy/2000-Exam-small.jpg) is a much better physics joke shirt that I find hilarious.

Comment: "The second law of thermodynamics is a tool of oppression."  Thank you for that, "It is symbolic of our struggle against oppression."

Comment: @Bye_World well i mean, its for people who have a certain sense of humor

Comment: @Bye_World While we're at it, [this shirt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067911/review-of-my-t-shirt-design) and [this shirt](https://www.amazon.com/AIRSPEED-VELOCITY-UNLADEN-SWALLOW-T-SHIRT/dp/B01GD88TOQ) are quite awesome and much better than the one here

Comment: It looks like a [Reader's Digest](http://www.rd.com) joke.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Theorem: "All odd numbers $> 1 $ are primes". Proof: $3$ is prime, $5$ is prime, $7$ is prime, $9\ \color{#f00}{\texttt{is not}}$ prime ( don't worry: it's an experimental error ),$11$ is prime$\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure by the chain rule it should be

$$\frac d{dx}(\pi^5+x^4)=5\pi^4\frac{d\pi}{dx}+4x^3$$

From here its just a matter of deciding which [$\pi$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_function) we are referring to!

Comment: Very amusing.  +1

Comment: Maybe, it' s something like $\left.{\mathrm{d}x^{5} \over \mathrm{d}x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ \pi} = 5\pi^{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a joke making fun at students who incorrectly use the power rule on powers of constants.

---

But the derivative of a constant is 0, because a constant does not change with respect to the variable, hence CONSTANT.

Comment: Wow, hilarious dude

Comment: It also pokes fun at the common student use of "derive" instead of "differentiate".

Comment: Eager to know, who was the downvoter. I have balanced it though :-)

Comment: @ErickWong, it's even worse: derivation is a special kind of function that satisfies the Leibniz product rule.